# ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, iframe, url-routing

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="menuController"> 
    <div data-ui-view="tab_PlaceLoader"></div>
</div>
```

in my HomePage, where are other tabs are loaded using routing.

I have,

```
 $stateProvider.state('Home', {
    views: {
        'tab_PlaceLoader':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'app/HomePage/TabHTMLFolder/HomeTab.html'
                }
    }
});
$stateProvider.state('Fund_Management', {
    views: {
        'tab_PlaceLoader':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'app/HomePage/TabHTMLFolder/FundMgt.html'
                }
    }
});
```

in my router.
And I have,

```
mainApp.controller('menuController', ['$scope','$state', function($scope,$state) {
  ...
  ....
  case "Home":
                    $state.go("Home");
                    break;
  case "Fund Management":
                    $scope.FundMgtURL = Constants.URL().Fund_Management; // Correct value is loaded from Constants file. 
                    $state.go("Fund_Management");
                    break;
  ....
  ...
}]);
mainApp.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
}]);
```

in my menuController Controller file.
I also have,

```
<div id="FundMgt">
    <div ng-controller="menuController">
       <iframe ng-src="{{FundMgtURL|trusted}}"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

in FundMgt.html page.

The issue is, the iframe gets loaded in the page, however, it is not showing the webpage whose address is being passed. In the browser's console, I see the issue :

```
GET https://www.mywebsite.com/ net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

I don't understand why "filter" is not called event though I have `{{FundMgtURL|trusted}}`.
I also tried with ng-src and just src in iframe.

Comment: You might not want to use a filter in this case. Just trust it directly in your controller. If you want to centralize the logic, you may want to create a directive. Not sure why this is failing, but there is likely an ordering issue with directives and filters.

Comment: When I am giving trust directly, I get
[$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7BFundMgtURL%…F%24sce%2Finsecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.mywebsite.com%252F